# HP ProBook 450 G10 microphone not working

Tags: arch-linux, alsa, microphone, pipewire, hp

I have an "HP ProBook 450 15.6 inch G10 Notebook PC" running arch (using pipewire) and the microphone does not work.

I tried using pavuctl and alsamixer to check if something was muted but nothing was. Everything works fine on windows on the same machine.

There is apparently a similar issue with the G7 model but I didn't find anything else about it online.

I tried with the built-in microphone and with a WH-1000XM4 Bluetooth headset (with both jack and Bluetooth) in vain, and I only get noise when I set the built-in audio card in duplex mode in pavuctl.

I'm not familiar enough with audio servers to debug that myself, I can provide any required logs but I'm not sure where to start.